AttachFile function not retrieving values from Data Extension
I'm facing an issue while using the AttachFile function in SFMC and would appreciate your help in understanding the behavior better.
When I use the function statically, assigning a value directly to my @entryAttachmentName1 variable, the email is sent with the pre-defined alias attached.txt:
%%[
var @entryAttachmentPath1, @entryAttachmentName1
set @entryAttachmentPath1 = "EmailAnexo/teste.txt"
set @entryAttachmentName1 = "attached.txt"
]%% 

However, when I attempt to fetch a value from my Data Extension to populate @entryAttachmentName1, AMPscript seems to default to using the imported file name instead of the alias defined in the Data Extension:
%%[
var @entryAttachmentPath1, @entryAttachmentName1
set @entryAttachmentPath1 = "EmailAnexo/teste.txt"
set @entryAttachmentName1 = AttributeValue("entryAttachmentName1")
AttachFile("FTP", @entryAttachmentPath1, @entryAttachmentName1)
]%% 

My Data Extension is configured as follows:
entryAttachmentName1: attached.txt
I expected the email to reflect the value of entryAttachmentName1, which is "attached.txt", without needing to assign it directly in the email body as I'm currently doing.
Does anyone know if the AttachFile function only accepts static values, or if there's a correct way to dynamically fetch values directly from the Data Extension?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

The AttachFile function does support dynamic values from a Data Extension, but you need to ensure that the values are correctly fetched and that the feature is appropriately provisioned for your account. If issues persist, it might be worth contacting Salesforce support for further assistance.
